# how to use reCaptcha v3 in wordpress custom login form?

Tags: ajax, login, forms, wp-login-form, captcha

I tried to create a **custom login form** and **custom register form** by ajax. I have been successful to make that and you can see my code below for custom login form.

the issue is, I need to use **reCaptcha V3** for my forms (login and register) for security. but I do not know how to add and use reCaptcha for my forms. so I need your help. what I have for custom login form by **ajax**:

**in Fuctions.php**

```
function karnetacom_scripts(){
    
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-forms-js',get_template_directory_uri().'/logreg/ajax-for-forms.js',array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_localize_script('ajax-forms-js','data',array(
        'ajax_url' =>  admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'redirecturlajax' => site_url(),
        
    ));

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','karnetacom_scripts');



// ajax login form
include get_template_directory() . '/logreg/ajax-login-form-function.php';
```

**login form as a template page**

```
<?php /* Template Name: login-form-ajax */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
        
        <div class="usereditprofile">
        
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
    <div class="singlepagecontent wwarningparent">
        <div class="singlewarning">
            <div class="singlewarningicon">
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="singlewarningtext">
            you are logged in!!!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>

        
    <div id="sh-ajax-login-wrapper" class="sh-ajax-login-wrapper">

        <div class="ajax-login-message error" style="display: none;"></div>

        <form action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" name="sh-ajax-login-form" id="sh-ajax-login-form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="usernameloginajax" id="usernameloginajax" placeholder="username or email" required>
            <input type="password" name="passwordloginajax" id="passwordloginajax" placeholder="password" required>
            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme">
            <label for="rememberme">remmeber me</label>
            <input type="submit" id="sh-ajax-login-submit" value="login">

            <?php wp_nonce_field('ajax-login-form-nonce','security'); ?>

        </form>
    </div>      
        
            
               
        
<?php } ?>  

        </div>
        
        
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**in ajax-for-forms.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    
    $('#sh-ajax-login-form').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this  = $(this);
        var $username = $this.find('#usernameloginajax').val();
        var $password = $this.find('#passwordloginajax').val();
        var $security = $this.find('#security').val();
        var $remember = $this.find('#rememberme').prop('checked');
        
        var $message = $('.ajax-login-message');
        
        $message.slideUp(300);
        
        if( $username === "" || $password === "" ){
            $message.html('<p>please fill all fields</p>').slideDown(300);
            return false;
        }

        //var $login_nonce  = $('meta[name="security"]').attr('content');
        //alert($_nonce);
        $.ajax({
            url:data.ajax_url,
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data : {
                action:'sh_ajax_login_form',
                username: $username,
                password: $password,
                remember: $remember,
                security: $security
            },
            success:function(response){

                if( response.error ){
                    $message.html('<p>'+response.message+'</p>').slideDown(300);
                }
                if( response.success ){
                    $message.removeClass('error').addClass('success').html('<p>'+response.message+'</p>').slideDown(300);
                    //window.location.href = 'http://7learn.dev/profile';
                    //window.location.href = data.redirecturlajax;
                }

            },
            error: function () {}

        });
    });
});
```

**in ajax-login-form-function.php**

```
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sh_ajax_login_form','sh_ajax_login_form');
function sh_ajax_login_form(){
    
    check_ajax_referer('ajax-login-form-nonce','security',true);

    $username = sanitize_text_field($_POST['username']);
    $password = sanitize_text_field($_POST['password']);
    $rememberme = isset($_POST['rememberme']);
    
    if( empty($username)  || empty($password) ){

        $result = array(
            'error' => true,
            'message' => 'please fill all fields'
        );
        wp_send_json($result);
        
    }
    
    $creds = array(
        'user_login'    => $username,
        'user_password' => $password,
        'rememember'    => $rememberme
    );
    $login_user = wp_signon($creds,false);

    if( is_wp_error($login_user)){

        $result = array(
            'error' => true,
            'message' => 'email or username is incorrect.'
        );
        wp_send_json($result);

    }

    $result = array(
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'you loggee in successfully'
    );
    wp_send_json($result);

}
```

**thanks a lot to help me**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found the Solution Finally Myself. here you are :)
.
**inside Fuctions.php**

```
function karnetacom_scripts(){
    
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-forms-js',get_template_directory_uri().'/logreg/ajax-for-forms.js',array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_localize_script('ajax-forms-js','data',array(
        'ajax_url' =>  admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'redirecturlajax' => site_url(),
        
    ));

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','karnetacom_scripts');



// ajax login form
include get_template_directory() . '/logreg/ajax-login-form-function.php';
```

**login form as a template page**

```
<?php /* Template Name: login-form-ajax */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
        
        <div class="usereditprofile">
        
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
    <div class="singlepagecontent wwarningparent">
        <div class="singlewarning">
            <div class="singlewarningicon">
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="singlewarningtext">
            you are logged in!!!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>

        
    <div id="sh-ajax-login-wrapper" class="sh-ajax-login-wrapper">

        <div class="ajax-login-message error" style="display: none;"></div>

        <form action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" name="sh-ajax-login-form" id="sh-ajax-login-form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="usernameloginajax" id="usernameloginajax" placeholder="username or email" required>
            <input type="password" name="passwordloginajax" id="passwordloginajax" placeholder="password" required>
            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme">
            <label for="rememberme">remmeber me</label>

            <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">

            <input type="submit" id="sh-ajax-login-submit" value="login">

            <?php wp_nonce_field('ajax-login-form-nonce','security'); ?>

        </form>
    </div>      
        
         
    <script async src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=[SITE_KEY]"></script>   
        
       
        
<?php } ?>  

        </div>
        
        
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**in ajax-for-forms.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    
    $('#sh-ajax-login-form').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this  = $(this);
        var $username = $this.find('#usernameloginajax').val();
        var $password = $this.find('#passwordloginajax').val();
        var $security = $this.find('#security').val();
        var $remember = $this.find('#rememberme').prop('checked');
        
        var $message = $('.ajax-login-message');
        
        $message.slideUp(300);
        
        if( $username === "" || $password === "" ){
            $message.html('<p>please fill all fields...</p>').slideDown(300);
            return false;
        } else {
            $message.html('<p>sending...</p>').slideDown(300);
        }

            grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                grecaptcha.execute('[site key]', { action: 'ajax_login_form' }).then(function (token) {
                    var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
                    recaptchaResponse.value = token;
                    
                    // Make the Ajax call here
                    $.ajax({
                        url:data.ajax_url,
                        type:'post',
                        dataType:'json',
                        data : {
                            action:'sh_ajax_login_form',
                            username: $username,
                            password: $password,
                            remember: $remember,
                            security: $security,
                            token: token,
                        },
                        success:function(response){

                            if( response.error ){
                                $message.html('<p>'+response.message+'</p>').slideDown(300);
                            }
                            if( response.success ){
                                $message.removeClass('error').addClass('success').html('<p>'+response.message+'</p>').slideDown(300);
                                //window.location.href = 'http://7learn.dev/profile';
                                //window.location.href = data.redirecturlajax;
                            }

                        },
                        error: function () {}

                    });
                });
            });
    });
    
});
```

**in ajax-login-form-function.php**

```
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sh_ajax_login_form','sh_ajax_login_form');
function sh_ajax_login_form(){
    
    check_ajax_referer('ajax-login-form-nonce','security',true);

    $username = sanitize_text_field($_POST['username']);
    $password = sanitize_text_field($_POST['password']);
    $rememberme = isset($_POST['rememberme']);
    
    if( empty($username)  || empty($password) ){

        $result = array(
            'error' => true,
            'message' => 'please fill all fields!!!'
        );
        wp_send_json($result);
                    
    } else {
    
        // Build POST request to get the reCAPTCHA v3 score from Google
        $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $recaptcha_secret = '[secret key]';
        //$recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];
        $recaptcha_response = sanitize_text_field($_POST['token']);
        
        // Make and decode POST request
        $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response);
        $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);
        
        //if ($recaptcha->success == true && $recaptcha->action == 'contact') {
        if ($recaptcha->success == true && $recaptcha->score >= 0.5 && $recaptcha->action == 'ajax_login_form') {
        //captacha validated successfully.
                    
                    $creds = array(
                        'user_login'    => $username,
                        'user_password' => $password,
                        'rememember'    => $rememberme
                    );
                    $login_user = wp_signon($creds,false);

                    if( is_wp_error($login_user)){

                        $result = array(
                            'error' => true,
                            'message' => 'email or username is incorrect.'
                        );
                        wp_send_json($result);

                    }

                    $result = array(
                        'success' => true,
                        'message' => 'you logged in successfully.'
                    );
                    wp_send_json($result);

        } else {
                
            //echo "Robot verification failed, please try again.";
            $result = array(
                'error' => true,
                'message' => 'Something went wrong. Please try again later'
            );
            wp_send_json($result);
                
        };
    
    };

}
```

God Bless You :)

Comment: Did you use any references for creating your ajax form for wordpress?